# Hiding an AJAX DIV tag... problems

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery code:

```
$('a[rel=close]').click(function() {
        alert('Close click!');
        $('div#purchasePanel').hide();
    });
```

This is used with:

```
<div id="purchasePanel">
<a href="#close" rel="close"><li> Close </li></a>
</div>
```

The alert() never gets called.

The DIV contents is shown and displayed using AJAX, which works fine. It's just this pesky close button that refuses to...

Comment: You might need to remove the <li> inside the <a> this may not be valid as technically the click is not on the a it's on the li

Comment: What do you get when you add $('a[rel=close]') in firebug console?

Comment: It will bubble up. But you are right, that `<li>` doesn't belong there at all!

Comment: not quite relevant: instead of using teh selector `div#purchasePanel`, it would be much faster to simply use `#purchasePanel` - jquery wouldnt have to go through all the divs!

Comment: I guess it's smart enough to see that an ID is used and only check if the found element has the correct tag and not iterate over the tags and check the ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you are adding the link after registering the handler.

The solution is using a [live event](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

```
$('a[rel=close]').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Close click!');
    $('div#purchasePanel').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the DIV is generated using AJAX you should `live` instead of `click`.

Answer (score 0):

If your script tag is before the link the handler is probably not getting attached. Try this:

```
<script>
// wait until everything has loaded
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[rel=close]').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault(); // needed to stop from loading the link
            alert('Close click!');
           $('#purchasePanel').hide();
    });
});
</script>
```